# How to use microsoft maren in ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, wine, language-support, microsoft

So there is this app which is called microsoft maren that allows you to type arabic using an english keyboard (you type in english characters and it transliterate it to arabic). Thing is this app is only avaialable for windows , so I tried installing it with wine but the problem is I can't seem to find the option for microsoft maren in the languages which in windows would be with the arabic language...
Any ideas ?

Comment: Using the linux command `apt-cache search arabic` shows me 73 entries.  Since we don't know what "microsoft maren" does (but it's probably not Open Source), I'll leave it up to you to see if any of the 73 help. Or, you could google "linux arabic input english keyboard".

Comment: Intercepting the keyboard in Microsoft Windows (which I assume "microsoft maren" does), is not in any way similar  to the way the task is accomplished with linux. I'm almost sure that `wine` doesn't emulate that behavior.

Comment: I didn't find what I want in the entries unfortunately. I guess I’ll just have to go with online sites that does the job of microsoft maren and copy text to where I need them. However the command you  mentioned was very useful , I found some interesting stuff in these entries so thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's a good alternative quite similar to Maren made by google](https://www.google.com/intl/ar/inputtools/try/) (and it supports many languages also).

You'll find a link to install it to google chrome. It wouldn't work across whole Ubuntu like Maren in Windows but I guess it's a partial solution.

Comment: I think having it for google chrome as a plugin is good enough , thanks alot!